# How to fix program not correctly identifying if an email is valid

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently coding a program for gcse computer science that works as an email validator in python, here is the code so far:

```
#OCR CODING CHALLENGE 3 - EMAIL VALIDATOR BY (My real name)

actual_email = ("123@email.net")
email = print(input("Enter your  email address"))

if (actual_email) != (email):
    print("Email is invalid")



elif (actual_email) == (email):
    print("Email is valid")
```

The problem is that it always says that the email is invalid even when it is not, before this it said it was always valid. So far I've tried - setting the actual_email as an input variable, using `if` instead of `elif`, using `else` instead of `elif` and putting `elif (actual_email) == (email): print("Email is valid")` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` function return nothing.

```
actual_email = "123@email.net"
email = input("Enter your  email address")
print(email)

if actual_email != email:
    print("Email is invalid")
else:
    print("Email is valid")
```